# SwiftUI Datepicker ios 15 background not blurry

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios15

I have noticed that on **IOS 14** on date/time selection the background its blurry and its most convenience for the user select and then click elsewhere to close to picker. Below is the IOs 14 screenshot:

[image: IOS 14]

On IOS15 the background is not blurry and the user can mistakenly click on a button wher trying to close the picker. Below is the IOS 15 screeshot:

[image: IOS15]

I would like to have the blurry effect on IOS 15 also. I tried looking for something regarding this change but I found nothing.

**Code for the Datepicker:**
Simple date picker inside a Form and a NavigationView.

```
NavigationView {
       Form {
             DatePicker("Date", selection: $startDate, displayedComponents: [ .date])
                    .accentColor(Color("primary"))
        }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... that is interesting. Could you provide the code you are using in the above example. Would help us investigate if there's anything that can be done to change this. Thanks

Comment: its too simple but i added a part of the code @Fogmeister

Comment: it may be simple. But you are asking for help with code that already exists. I can try to help but there are a million ways to write an app. It's much easier for you to share your code than it is for me to try and guess what your code is and write it from scratch. Sharing your code helps other people to help you.

Comment: This is standard control with standard behavior and they change behavior of standard controls with almost every OS version, so any intervention in this is a hack which at least might stop working with any new OS update, at worst your app might not pass AppStore review. Just be aware.

Comment: @Asperi im not looking for a hack nor intervention. Just if there is a way to have the same behaviour as IOS 14, maybe a modifier or a custom DatePickerStyle